# AppImage updates conflicts with its .desktop file

Tags: linux, package, appimage

I have a couple of AppImage files in my system (Fedora38). I need all of those AppImage icons in my app tray. I manually created the .desktop files, and it works fine.
But when an app gets updated, most of the time, that modifies its filename. Hence, the icon stops working. And I need to go to the .desktop file and modify the file path to work again.

What is the best workaround for this issue? I tried 'appimage launcher', but it did not provide icons for most of my AppImages.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try to correct this problem also in my application and update thru comment here.

Comment: I work around this issue in my application. Pl help me in working out.
 I want to know one thing. All the appimage files contain its update information. But there is no default tool coming with the linux. (The default package manager (like yum, dnf, apt, rpm) updates only the packages relevant to theirs)

Are you manually updating appimage files or are you using any external tools for automatic update? What tool do you use?
Ref-1.  https://docs.appimage.org/packaging-guide/optional/updates.html
Ref-2.  https://github.com/AppImageCommunity/AppImageUpdate

Answer (score -1):

I've created an application to install appimage applications. My application name is Happim. (Happim stands for Handle Appimage)

After installing happim, What all you need to do is to 1. launch happim by click the icon, 2. Type your appimage application name. 3. Select your preferred icon and appimage file through gui, 4. Click install. Now, your favorite appimage's icon will be available among your installed programs. You can add to favorite by right clicking and selecting 'Add to favorite'.

Free to use. Available in github.

Ensure the necessary packages have been installed.

```
git clone https://github.com/suramuthurs/Happim.git
cd Happim
python3 install.py
```

Go through my readme.md in github for the solution in case if it doesn't work